# split comma for each entry in array

Tags: javascript

Any better ideas of converting

`["1","2","3,4","5","6","7,8,9"]` to `["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]`

What i want to achieve is create a smaller amount of code while keeping it simple.

```
var arr=["1","2","3,4","5","6","7,8,9"];

var tmp=[];
for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
  tmp=tmp.concat(arr[i].split(","));
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/iJG2aPZ3JAFvsulxJDQe?p=preview

I used simple js but you can use any kind of library to reduce the code.

Comment: `["1","2","3,4","5","6","7,8,9"].join().match(/\d+/g)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use join() and split together.

```
arr.join(",").split(",");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8AhZ/)

Comment: i realy feel like a retard for not thinking about that

Comment: @Marcio You and me both!

Comment: too short, consider cheating.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the replacement in-place:

```
for( var i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    arr.splice.apply(arr,[i,1].concat(arr[i].split(",")));
}
```